# Organize and validate companies in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I want to use Keycloak for my application. Since our current data model expects a user name, password and the abbreviation of a company, I would like to know if there is a way to add an additional parameter to the login screen in Keycloak where the abbreviation of the company has to be specified. During the authentication process it should be checked whether the user belongs to this company and if so, the token which is created should contain the company's abbreviation.

So far I manged to modify the login theme like this:

[Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWQ8A.png)

I know it is possible to add additional information to a token via client scopes and attribute mappers, but as far as I know, this is only possible for single users.

Also I'd like to know, which is the best way to administrate companies in keycloak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Does anyone have any ideas?